# How to use controller from vendor in laravel routes.php file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this in routes.php :

```
Route::post('myFunction', ['uses' => 'MyPackage\MyController@updateMeta']);
```

And I get this error :

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\MyPackage\MyController does not exist
```

Any idea how to use controller from vendor in routes.php ?

Comment: Make sure the namespace on MyController is right. Should be `namespace App\Http\Controllers\MyPackage\MyController;`

Comment: Laravel use base namespace "App\Http\Controllers" by default ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place another `\` in front of the namespace. By default, Laravel will search for controllers in `App\Http\Controllers\`. By placing another `\` in front you tell Laravel to start searching in the root namespace.

```
Route::post('myFunction', ['uses' => '\MyPackage\MyController@updateMeta']);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, please mark this as the answer so future developers with this problem will find the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add '\' in the beginning of the controller namespace:

By default, routes.php assumes your controller is in 'App\Http\Controllers' namespace but adding '\' will cause it to look in the root namespace.

```
Route::get('/vendor-control', '\Vendor1\Vendormanager\controllers\Vendor1Controller@view');
```